# Vector cross product properties?

Tags: cross-product

I have a 3x3 symmetric matrix

$$C=AB^T+BA^T,$$

where both $A$ and $B$ are 3x1 vectors.

How may I prove
$$C(A\times B)=0?$$

I believe the key is the properties of vector cross product.

Comment: Have you tried brute-forcing the formulae?

Comment: @ncmathsadist meaning, expressing each matrix/vector in terms of its elements and prove the equality?

Comment: @SibbsGambling Yes, that's the brute force solution. It won't be pretty, but it will certainly work. Also note that the result is a $3 \times 1$ vector, so it is enough to take an arbitrary entry and show that it is zero (with the right notation, you won't have to deal with all 3 rows individually).

Comment: @EricTressler Right, I can do that, but I am wishing for a more elegant "high-level" solution..

Comment: The rows of $C$ are linear combinations of $A$ and $B$, and $A \times B$ is orthogonal to both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  For any $3\times1$ vectors $u,v$ we have
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}
  \v u^T\v v=\v u\cdot\v v\ .$$
In particular,
$$B^T(A\times B)=B\cdot(A\times B)\ .$$
There is a very important fact that you should know about this kind of expression involving both the dot and cross products.

**Comment**.  My first equation is not correct, strictly speaking, since the LHS is a matrix and the RHS is a scalar.  However, there is no important difference between a $1\times1$ matrix and a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see how this hint helps solve the question.

Comment: Do you know what can be said about $B\cdot(A\times B)$?

Comment: It is zero, since $A\times B$ is orthogonal to $B$.

Comment: OK, so take the product you are interested in, $C(A\times B)$, and do a bit of algebra.